# Question about proof of the product of a finite number of T1 spaces is a T1 space.

Tags: general-topology

**Show that the product of a finite number of T1 spaces is a T1 space.**

Since each $X_i$ is a $T_1$ space, $$\prod_{i \in I} X_i \backslash \{x_i\} = \{(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n):a_i \in X_i \land (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \neq (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)\} $$ is open, and  $$(\prod_{i \in I} X_i) \backslash \{(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)\} = \{(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n):a_i \in X_i \land (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \neq (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)\}$$

has the same definition as the first product, which implies that it's open.

$\therefore$ The two are equal and finite product of $T_1$ spaces is a $T_1$ space.

Is this correct to assume that $\prod X_i \backslash \{x_i\} = (\prod X_i) \backslash \{(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)\}$ because the definitions are the same?

Comment: Yes, this is fine. A slighty easier version of the same idea can be used if you’ve proved two important facts. $(1)$ A space $X$ is $T_1$ if and only if $\{x\}$ is closed for each $x\in X$. $(2)$ The Cartesian product of closed sets is closed. Then for each $p=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ in the product we have $\{p\}=\prod_{k=1}^n\{x_k\}$; if the factor spaces are $T_1$, each $\{x_k\}$ is closed, so $\{p\}$ is closed, and the product is $T_1$.

Answer (score 1):

To make things more simple you can focus on closed sets instead of open sets.

If $X$ denotes the product of $X_1,\dots,X_n$ and $\pi_i:X\to X_i$ the projections then a singleton $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\in X$ equals $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\pi_i^{-1}(\{x_i\})$. The singletons in every $X_i$ are closed (since $X_i$ is $T_1$) and the $\pi_i$ are continuous so we are dealing with a finite intersection of closed sets. So it is closed itself. We conclude that singletons are closed in $X$, or quivalently that $X$ is $T_1$.

Comment: This shows BTW that the restriction to finte products is bogus. It holds for any product.

Comment: The concept of projections isn't introduced in my book until the next section, is there a way to show this without projections?